# integrate `openai-whisper` tokenizer with spaCy

Tags: spacy, tokenize, openai-whisper

I am trying to use the tokenizer from `openai-whisper` to be used as the tokenizer for `spaCy`.

Im doing the following but it is giving errors, what is the correct way to use whisper tokenizer as a custom tokenizer in `spaCy`.

```
import spacy
import en_core_web_sm
from whisper.tokenizer import Tokenizer, get_tokenizer
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
nlp.tokenizer = Tokenizer
```

The issue is that when `openai-whisper` tokenizes " Toby makes fun", it considers the first " " (space) as a token. When passing through `spaCy` tokenizer it also recognizes this, but while finding the entity, it discards any empty spaces. Here the entity output is "Toby" but I need it to be " Toby"

```
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
ref_doc = nlp(" Toby makes fun")
print([(X.text, X.label_) for X in ref_doc.ents])
# ref_doc.text = " Toby makes fun"
# but ref_doc.ent.text = "Toby"
```